# How to plot relationship of three parameters with a Group?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, multiple-instances

I have a dataframe as below:

```
GR  CYT EMT PRO
High    8   5   8
Low 8   2   2
High    6   2   10
High    5   7   4
Low 7   2   1
Low 5   10  4
High    6   3   5
Low 8   1   10
High    4   7   5
High    2   3   8
Low 3   2   7
Low 5   7   1
High    7   7   2
High    5   1   3
```

I want plot all the parameters in a figure using R. I want check relationship of three parameters CYT, EMT, PRO with GR.

```
df <- data.frame(
  GR = c("High", "Low", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "High", "Low", "High", "High", "Low", "Low", "High", "High"),
  CYT = c(8, 8, 6, 5, 7, 5, 6, 8, 4, 2, 3, 5, 7, 5),
  EMT = c(5, 2, 2, 7, 2, 10, 3, 1, 7, 3, 2, 7, 7, 1),
  PRO = c(8, 2, 10, 4, 1, 4, 5, 10, 5, 8, 7, 1, 7, 3)
)
```

I have tried something like following:

```
# Melt the data to long format for better plotting
df_long <- reshape2::melt(df, id.vars = "GR")

# Create a grouped bar plot
ggplot(df_long, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = GR)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  labs(title = "Relationship of Parameters with GR",
       x = "Parameter",
       y = "Value") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: Output]

Are there any other way to represent the data?

Comment: What kind of plot do you want, and where are you stuck in your code?

Comment: @jpsmith are there any possibilty of any other plots other than barplots?

Comment: We don't know what your data means. What is the relationship between high and low GR? The other variables?
Considering you have multiple high and low value a bar graph doesn't show variations. Are these important?

This could be a boxplot, a scatter plot, or both combined.

[This site](https://www.data-to-viz.com/) has a nice flowchart style graph to show how to select an appropriate graph and their caveats.

Comment: Maybe try `geom_boxplot` instead of a bar plot?

Comment: It appears you are looking for basic statistical assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a boxplot to show the relationship between groups.
And see how the averages of the groups change by changing the level from 1 to 2 and 3.
This diagram is often used for hypothesis testing

```
df_long <- reshape2::melt(df, id.vars = "GR")
```

ggplot(df_long, aes(x= variable, y = value, col = GR)) +
geom_boxplot()
[image]

You can also study the interaction between H-L and groups.

`ggplot(df_long, aes(col= variable, y = value, x = GR)) + geom_boxplot()`

[image]